# how to use oauth with Google.GData.Analytics

Tags: c#, oauth, client, gdata

I want to create an AnalyticsRequest object using oauth. Everything is working accept the callback page.
With the client lib for youtube my code looks like this;

```
                settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(appName, clientID, developerKey(string)Session["token"]);
            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
```

and for analytics

```
gt.request = new AnalyticsRequest(new RequestSettings());
```

but I cant seem to find the right overload of the constructor of RequestSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the svn of [google-gdata .Net library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/), there is a [full example with AnalyticsRequest](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/?r=936#cs%2Fsamples%2Fanalytics).

Comment: Not with oauth: service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);

Answer (score 0):

The library includes an OAuth 2.0 sample that uses both a service class (GroupsService) and a request class (ContactsRequest) and should be easy to adapt to use the Analytics API:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs

I'm not an expert on the Analytics API but I understand it supports OAuth 2.0 as it is also listed in the OAuth 2.0 Playground:

https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/